# how can I merge multiple column in one column and separated by '-'?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, command-line

I have a table as below:

```
1  10  15
2  2   25
1  10  26
```

I like to merge them and make a new column in linux, like below:

```
1  10  15  1:10-15
2  2   25  2:2-25
1  10  26  1:10-26
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
awk '{print $0" "$1":"$2"-"$3}' file

1  10  15 1:10-15
2  2   25 2:2-25
1  10  26 1:10-26
```

Comment: If the input is tab-separated, this will print tab-separated fields except for the last separator, which will be a single space. Compare it with e.g. `'{ $(NF+1) = $1":"$2"-"$3; print; }'`.

Answer (score 0):

Command:

```
sed "s/.*/& &/g" filename | sed -r "s/\s+/ /g"| sed "s/ /:/4g"
```

output

```
1 10 15 1:10:15
2 2 25 2:2:25
1 10 26 1:10:26
```

Comment: notice the last delimiter is a dash, not a colon. I'd also point out that `sed` can take multiple script arguments, so instead of 3 `sed` calls, you could use: `sed -r -e "one..." -e "two ..." -e "three ..."`